# Pandas aggregation with dictionary `count_if=1` ignored.

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to aggregate a Pandas DataFrame using `sum` and get `NaN` if all values of a group are `NaN`. This works in the case of `.agg('sum', min_count=1)` but the `min_count` is ignored when using a aggregation dictionary.

What am I missing here and how can I fix it?

#### Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'l':  ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
     'v': [-1, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
     'w': [-1, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

`sum` would return `0.0` for groups that are all `NaN` but we can fix that by using the arguments `min_count=1`:

```
print(df.groupby('l')['v'].agg('sum'))
> l
> a   -1.0
> b    2.0
> c    0.0
> Name: v, dtype: float64

print(df.groupby('l')['v'].agg('sum', min_count=1))
> l
> a   -1.0
> b    2.0
> c    NaN
> Name: v, dtype: float64
```

But when using a dictionary, it seems to ignore the keyword argument.

```
df.groupby('l').agg({'v':'sum', 'w':'mean'}, min_count=1)
> Name: v, dtype: float64
>      v    w
> l          
> a -1.0 -1.0
> b  2.0  1.0
> c  0.0  NaN
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use lambda function:

```
df1 = df.groupby('l').agg({'v': lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1), 'w': 'mean'})
print (df1)
     v    w
l          
a -1.0 -1.0
b  2.0  1.0
c  NaN  NaN
```